# How dynamic map service name to ENV var

Tags: docker-compose

Example:

```
my-server:
  image: my-server:latest
  ports:
    - 1234:1234
proxy:
  image: lb:latest
  environment:
    - BACKEND=${VAR}??? # must be resolve as 'my-server'
```

The server name can be changed to any name, but the proxy has a entry-point script where the variable will be substituted in the BACKEND to config.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `.env` file to define your variable. This file will be placed in the same directory as your `docker-compose.yml` file.

When you run `docker-compose`, it will read this value and use it. Using your example, your `.env` file would look something like this:

```
VAR=my-server
```

and, the line:

`- BACKEND=${VAR}??? # must be resolve as 'my-server'`

would become just:

```
- BACKEND=${VAR}
```

or

```
BACKEND: ${VAR}
```