# How to assign port dynamically using docker-compose?

Tags: docker, dynamic, docker-compose

I am doing dockerization of project. I wanted to assign port in the docker-compose file dynamically.

I have searched over the internet but I am not able to find any solution. Any suggestions are welcome

```
services:
  db:
    image: "mysql:latest"
    restart: on-failure
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=
    ports:
      - 23316:3305
```

Docker-compose port should not be assign to particular port. It should be dynamically generated.

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/q/42122860/464252?  It sounds like you are looking for a way to dynamically change your docker-compose file.  Maybe you can try assigning the port via environment variables?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create separate `.env` files to keep your environment dependent variables, and refer to those vars in your `compose` file as below:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: "mysql:latest"
    restart: on-failure
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=
    ports:
      - ${DB_PORT}:3306
```

#### development `.env` file

```
DB_PORT=3306
```

#### production `.env` file

```
DB_PORT=23316
```

Copy either the `.env` file above to your server, and place it in the same dir with your `docker-compose.yml` file.

When you run the `docker-compose` command, it will automatically replace the env vars in the compose file with what you have defined in `.env` file.

Suppose you have deployed the production `.env` file with your `docker-compose.yml`, then when you run command

```
docker-compose up -d
```

`DB_PORT` will be replace with `23316`.

#### Reference:

1. [Environment variables in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/)
2. [Environment file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use environment variables:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    restart: on-failure
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=
    ports:
      - ${MYSQL_PORT}:3306
```

and then just define them at runtime like this:

```
MYSQL_PORT=3306 docker-compose up
```